# Php validation form without char

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem.I need that the user can not send the form without having to write something
I have this form :

```html
<div id="content" class="inner-wrapper reg">
 <div id="mside">
    <div class="section goback">
 <div class="btn-back"><a class="back" onClick="history.go(-1)"><?= $lang['profile']['back'] ?></a></div>
    </div>
  <div class="section register">
   <form id="mail-cons" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    
    <div class="step2">
    <ul class="step-ul">
     <h2>Asesoría vía correo electrónico</h2>

<?//Primul pas pt user, descrierea problemei
if(loggedtype()=='user' AND $data['user_description']==''){?>
     <div class="step-message sys-info"><img class='small icon' src='<?=$url_base?>css/images/icons/information.png' alt=''/> <?=$lang['mc']['user_step1']?></div>

     <div class="row  mail-cnsl">
      </div>
     <div class="row">
          <textarea id="descriere2 " name="descriere" class="tinymce" rows="20" cols="50" style="width: 554px; height: 517px;"><?php echo $_REQUEST["descriere"];?></textarea>
     </div>
  <div class="row submit mail-cnsl">
      <input type="submit" name="submitdesc"  value="Enviar solicitud!"  />
     </div>

   <? } ?>
```

And this function for validation:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_required(field,alerttxt)
{
with (field)
  {
  if (value==null||value=="")
    {
    alert(alerttxt);return false;
    }
  else
    {
    return true;
    }
  }
}

function validate_form(thisform)
{
with (thisform)
  {
  if(window.clicked) return true;
  if (validate_required(user_description_extra,"Por favor, introduzca el motivo del rechazo!")==false)
   {user_description_extra.focus();return false;}
    }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_length(f,a,l){
    z=f.value;
    x=z.length;
    if (x<l){alert (a); f.focus(); return false;}
    return true;
}
</script>
```

And this function for submit :

```js
if(isset($_POST['submitdesc'])){
   $upd = mysql_query("UPDATE discussion SET active='0' WHERE id='".$_GET['iddisc']."'") or die(mysql_error());

   $sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discussion WHERE id='".$_GET['iddisc']."'") or die(mysql_error());
   $data = mysql_fetch_array($sel);

   $upd_mc = mysql_query("UPDATE mail_counseling SET new_user=0, new_cons=1, user_description='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriere'])."' WHERE id_disc='".$_GET['iddisc']."'") or die(mysql_error());

   //Notificari
   if($_SESSION['loggedin']['type']=='user'){
      $insid = $user['id_user'];
      $type1 = 'user';
      $type2 = 'client';
   }else{
      $insid = $cons['id_counselor'];
      $type1 = 'consilier';
      $type2 = 'counselor';
   }



   $insnotifs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mc_notifs (type,id_user,message) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['loggedin']['type']."','".$insid."','".mysql_real_escape_string($message)."')") or die(mysql_error());
   //End Notificari

   //Send notification mail
   $query_tpl_mail = "SELECT * FROM mails WHERE id_mails='6'";
   $tpl_mail = mysql_query($query_tpl_mail, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
   $row_tpl_mail = mysql_fetch_assoc($tpl_mail);

   $subject = $row_tpl_mail['title_mail'.$lng_s_tb];
   $message = $row_tpl_mail['description'.$lng_s_tb];
   avertizare_mail($cons["email"],$subject,$lang['mc']['notif1']);
   avertizare_mail($user["email"],$subject,$lang['mc']['notif11']);
   header("Location: ".$url_base."$tip_user-account/mail-counseling/ok/");
   exit;

}
```

But don't work .Can I help my?

Comment: Can you show the rest of your html? How are you actually calling the validation function?

Comment: only this form need to validation

Comment: @Darren Sweeney can help my?

Comment: If you answer the comments - show more html and how are you calling the validation function?

Comment: I send to my email but here don't posible to insert more code

Comment: @Darren Sweeney ???

Comment: You can edit the question and add more code - if you can't then I can't help unfortunately

Comment: @ Darren Sweeney done

Comment: @ Darren Sweeney help my please?

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on the client side validation. Turning off javascript may leave your form vulnerable. You must do this work in php more securely and easily.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitdesc'])){

    $desc = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['descriere']))); 

    if(isset($desc)){
           $upd = mysql_query("UPDATE discussion SET active='0' WHERE id='".$_GET['iddisc']."'") or die(mysql_error());

   $sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discussion WHERE id='".$_GET['iddisc']."'") or die(mysql_error());
   $data = mysql_fetch_array($sel);

   $upd_mc = mysql_query("UPDATE mail_counseling SET new_user=0, new_cons=1, user_description='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descriere'])."' WHERE id_disc='".$_GET['iddisc']."'") or die(mysql_error());

   //Notificari
   if($_SESSION['loggedin']['type']=='user'){
      $insid = $user['id_user'];
      $type1 = 'user';
      $type2 = 'client';
   }else{
      $insid = $cons['id_counselor'];
      $type1 = 'consilier';
      $type2 = 'counselor';
   }



   $insnotifs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mc_notifs (type,id_user,message) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['loggedin']['type']."','".$insid."','".mysql_real_escape_string($message)."')") or die(mysql_error());
   //End Notificari

   //Send notification mail
   $query_tpl_mail = "SELECT * FROM mails WHERE id_mails='6'";
   $tpl_mail = mysql_query($query_tpl_mail, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
   $row_tpl_mail = mysql_fetch_assoc($tpl_mail);

   $subject = $row_tpl_mail['title_mail'.$lng_s_tb];
   $message = $row_tpl_mail['description'.$lng_s_tb];
   avertizare_mail($cons["email"],$subject,$lang['mc']['notif1']);
   avertizare_mail($user["email"],$subject,$lang['mc']['notif11']);
   header("Location: ".$url_base."$tip_user-account/mail-counseling/ok/");
   exit;
    }else{
       ?><script>alert('Empty text field is not allowed.')</script><?php
    }
}
```

Comment: all your after-submit codes. i re-edited my answer. you may check it

Comment: It still does not work . Get over . If you do not write anything, everything can send

Comment: This is a bad answer, the OP is about client side validation, not server

Comment: @Alex, If you have used the pasted code, please again try the re-edited code, there was an error.

Comment: @Darren, I don't think so. Alex is already using php query. I don't think a reason why i may not use server side validation?. After all none client-side validation may work if javascript is set off.

Comment: your code is $desc = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['descriere']))); but i have error when i run...no is corect $desc = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['descriere'])); ? whitout one ) ??

Comment: i try now code but form passed when don't type nothing.

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar The point is that for this question, we assume javascript is on - that is the whole point of the validation

Comment: "Turning off javascript may leave your form vulnerable." - You can just use the `required` attribute on the input and let the browser handle it, but even then it's not JavaScript that makes the form vulnerable. Never trust anything the user sends.